# Get Initials of full names with accented characters through REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the initials of a full name even if the name has accents or dots or comma.

If I have the name:

> "Raúl, Moreno. Rodríguez Carlos"

I get "RLMRGC".

my code is:

`user.displayName.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]/gm).join('').toUpperCase()`

I want to get "RMRC". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can your names  start with non-`[A-Z]` uppercase letters? `Иван Иванович Иванов` => `ИИИ`?

Comment: If you are targeting Chrome or any other ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environments, I'd recommend `.match(/(?<![\p{N}\p{L}])\p{L}/gu).join('').toUpperCase()`

Comment: Regex can't be used to extract names at all. It doesn't know the difference between Dog, Sam, or God.

Answer (score 1):

A fully Unicode compatible solution should match any letter after a char other than letter or digit.

Here are two solutions: 1) an [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) based solution for any browser, and 2) an ECMAScript 2018 only JS environment compatible solution.

```js
var regex = XRegExp("(?:^|[^\\pL\\pN])(\\pL)");
console.log( XRegExp.match("Łukasz Żak", regex, "all").map(function(x) {return x.charAt(x.length - 1);}).join('').toUpperCase() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

ECMAScript 2018 compliant solution:

```js
// ONLY WORKING IN ECMAScript2018 COMPLIANT JS ENVIRONMENT!
var regex = /(?<![\p{N}\p{L}])\p{L}/gu; 
console.log( "Łukasz Żak".match(regex).join('').toUpperCase() );
// => ŁŻ
```

NOTE:

- `(?:^|[^\pL\\pN])(\pL)` matches start of a string and any char but letter and digit and then matches any letter (since the char matched by the first non-capturing group is not necessary, `.map(function(x) {return x.charAt(x.length - 1);})` is required to get the last char of the match)
- `(?<![\p{N}\p{L}])\p{L}` matches any letter (`\p{L}`) that is not preceded with a digit or letter (see the negative lookbehind `(?<![\p{N}\p{L}])`)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might work:

```js
const regex = /[^A-Z]/gm;
const str = `Raúl, Moreno. Rodríguez Carlos`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with REGEX):

```js
const data = "Raúl, Moreno. Rodríguez Carlos";
const result = data.match(/\b[A-Z]/gm);
console.log(result);
```

other solution without REGEX:

```js
const data = "Ędward Ącki";
const result = [...data].filter((c, k, arr) => c !== ' ' && (k == 0 || arr[k-1] == ' ' ))
console.log(result);
```